# Remove the abort controller after cancelling call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, abortcontroller

I have managed to cancel my http request via axios and redux.
This is what I have so far. I have a modal, this modal is saving data to a database, once I click on the abort, i cancel the dispatch action (the axios call made to save data)  in the useEffect. Let 's say now the user exit the modal and decide some other time to go back on the modal to save its data again, the cancel signal is still on the route. How do I clear up the abort controller ? is there a way to do a clean up ?

Here is my service file :

```
           export const sync = (l, obj, pId, controller) => {
              let a = { ...obj };
     
      return axios.post(`/${l}/f/ff/Create`, {
       signal: controller.signal
  });
};
```

my action file

```
export const save =
    (l, el, pId,controller ) => async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: SAVE_REQUEST });

            await sync(l, el, pId, controller);

            dispatch({
                type: SAVE_SUCCESS,
                payload: el,
            });
        } catch ( error) {
                dispatch({ type: SAVE_FAIL, payload: error});
            }
        }
  };
```

and my component

```
    const { current: controller } = useRef(null);

const handleAbort = () => {
            controller.current?.abort();
            controller.current = null;
        };

  useEffect(() => {
   controller.current = new AbortController();
    dispatch(save(l,el,p.id,controller)
    return () => {
            handleAbort();
        };
    },[])

  
  <div>
<Modal>
<progressbar/>
  <button onclick={handleAbort()}>abort</button>
<button >exit</button>
</Modal>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually by destructuring the ref immediately, you lose the functionality of the ref. Better to declare an empty ref and assign the AbortController to it just prior to your dispatch call in the useEffect, then clear it in your `handleAbort` handler after aborting.

Comment: I have updated the code to try what you said, could you tell me where the issue is ? thanks @pilchard thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are still destructuring `const { current: controller } = useRef(null);` should just be `const controller = useRef(null);` And you need to pass the `current` property to your dispatch `save(l,el,p.id,controller.current)`

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I managed to make it work

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working.